# Can't access internet in android emulator in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-wifi

I try to connect internet in emulator but it is not connected.
I add DNS and also done cold boot,wipe data all the things.
But it is not connected what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think your defender firewall maybe block the internet connection. Go to start menu and find defender firewall and then go to advanced settings and click inbound rules. Then, choose option program (exe). Copy and paste the path location of your emulator and then choose option allow connection.